# maven integration-test phase attaches jbossall-client.jar in the classpath

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up the integration-test phase with maven in my java project. I don't have any dependencies on jboss (except for jboss-common-core which gets pulled transitively by hibernate-entitymanager). My setup for the fail-safe plugin is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn integration-test -Dmaven.failsafe.debug` and hookup my debugger and evaluate `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` I see a jbossall-client.jar in the classpath! When I run the tests locally in IntellJ 122.327, the classpath does not contain jbossall-client.jar. I've been trying to figure out why this jar gets added to the classpath. Has anyone else experienced this before? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I tried removing jbossall-client from my .m2/repository directory and running the clean and package phases only, it seems like my project does indeed have a dependency on this because this jar gets downloaded upon running package. Still weird because my pom has no direct or transitive dependency on this jar. Also when I try excluding it from being added to the classpath when running with the failsafe plugin by adding the configuration

```
<classpathDependencyExcludes>org.jboss.client:jbossall-client</classpathDependencyExcludes>
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12:integration-test
 for parameter classpathDependencyExcludes: Cannot assign configuration entry 'classpathDependencyExcludes' 
with value 'org.jboss.client:jbossall-client' of type java.lang.String
 to property of type java.util.List -> [Help 1]
```

The [failsafe plugin website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) states that the tag should have value `groupId:artifactId` which is what I have. Any ideas why this is failing?

SECOND UPDATE: Just realized that there is a typo in the fail-safe plugin [webpage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html). In their example:

```
  <classpathDependencyExcludes>
    <classpathDependencyExcludes>org.apache.commons:commons-email</classpathDependencyExcludes>
  </classpathDependencyExcludes>
```

should really be

```
  <classpathDependencyExcludes>
    <classpathDependencyExclude>org.apache.commons:commons-email</classpathDependencyExclude>
  </classpathDependencyExcludes>
```

Now I can get passed the parse error, but jbossall-client is still being loaded into the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down the problem, the classpathDependencyExclude tag works as expected. I had stupidly excluded the wrong groupId (I was excluding org.jboss.client:jbossall-client, when the transitive dependency was jboss:jbossall-client). Another thing I observed was that the jbossall-client was a 3rd level transitive dependency (ie it is the second child of the direct dependency; myproject -> A -> B -> jbossall-client), which is defined in the parent pom of a maven submodule (in my example B is a submodule of a larger project). When I check maven dependency using the dependency plugin, it reports that the actual project dependency does not include jbossall-client. However for some reason integration-test phase seems to include it in the classpath. I'm going to investigate further, but for now the hack works.